# How to set up email to be sent via Excel for projects due within 7 days?

Tags: excel, vba

[Image of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WK0e.png)

I am trying set up email notifications to be sent people in my department whenever there is an upcoming due date within 7 days.  Currently the issue is whenever I run the module, it sets up emails for anything that is before the due date.  However, I want emails to be set up for projects that are due within 7 days.  So if the project is 10 days out, I do not want an email sent, same project where it is already past due.

In addition, I would like the emails to be sent to the person responsible of the project, but not if they have indicated that they already completed the project in Column I.

I have Project names in Column B, Emails in Column F, Due Dates in Column H, and Column K would show "Email Sent" if the script sends the email.  If the email has already been sent previously then it would skip that row.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim lLastRow As Long
        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim sSendTo As String
        Dim sSendCC As String
        Dim sSendBCC As String
        Dim sSubject As String
        Dim sTemp As String

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        OutApp.Session.Logon

        ' Change the following as needed
        sSendCC = ""
        sSendBCC = ""
        sSubject = "Project Log Due Date Reached"

        lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        For lRow = 3 To lLastRow
            If Cells(lRow, 11) <> "Email Sent" Then
                If Cells(lRow, 8) - Date <= 7 And Cells(1Row, 8) - Date > 0 Then
                    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

                    On Error Resume Next
                    With OutMail
                        .To = Cells(1Row, 6) 
                        If sSendCC > "" Then .CC = sSendCC
                        If sSendBCC > "" Then .BCC = sSendBCC
                        .Subject = sSubject

                        sTemp = "Hello!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                        sTemp = sTemp & "The due date has been reached "
                        sTemp = sTemp & "for this project:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                        ' Assumes project name is in column B
                        sTemp = sTemp & "    " & Cells(lRow, 2)
                        sTemp = sTemp & "Please take the appropriate"
                        sTemp = sTemp & "action." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
                        sTemp = sTemp & "Thank you!" & vbCrLf

                        .Body = sTemp
                        ' Change the following to .Send if you want to
                        ' send the message without reviewing first
                        .Send
                    End With
                    Set OutMail = Nothing

                    Cells(lRow, 11) = "Email Sent"
                    Cells(lRow, 12) = "E-mail sent on: " & Now()
                End If
            End If
        Next lRow
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you edit your question - link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55055584/edit) - and specify what problem(s) you are having?

Comment: And add some sample data

Comment: and get rid of this: `On Error Resume Next` there's no need for it in this code and it will hide real issues that may arise and can be handled differently .... in this line :`If Cells(lRow, 7) <= 7 Then`, are you sure you have the right math in column G to calculate the days?

Answer (score 0):

Seany, Scott's right - take out the "On Error Resume Next" statement as this suppresses errors you'd rather see and troubleshoot at design time. And, you said Column F; which when using the Cells property, the column is the second parameter and you have "7" where "F" would be "6."

For comparing dates, I'd suggest *DateDiff*

Ex:

```
DateDiff("d", ws.Cells(1, 1).Value, ws.Cells(1, 1).Value + 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make a helper column in free column say `L`and put the formula `=TODAY()-G2`and draw down. Replace your following lines

```
  For lRow = 3 To lLastRow
        If Cells(lRow, 10) <> "Email Sent" Then
            If Cells(lRow, 7) <= 7 Then
  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

With

```
For lRow = 3 To lLastRow
     If Cells(lRow, 10) <> "Email Sent" Then   
         If (Cells(lRow, 12) >= -7) And (Cells(lRow, 12) <= 0) Then
 Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

It works for me. You can also follow any other logic based on this logic.